# get the Date and the Month from data-date-format

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap date picker and i want to parse only the date and month to the variables .

```
   <div class="input-append date dp3" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
    <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" id="RG_Date" name="RG_Date" value="12.02.2013" readonly><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
    </div>

getDate = 12
getMonth = 02
```

like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF DATE IS LIKE 30.08.2013

USE THE FOLLOWING CODE.

```
var myDate=$('#RG_Date').val();
var myDateArray=myDate.split('.');
var getDate = myDateArray[0];
var getMonth = myDateArray[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right , you should do sth like this

```
var day;
var month;

$('#RG_Date').datepicker()
   .on('changeDate', function(e){
   _m = e.date.getMonth() + 1,
   month = (_m > 9 ? _m : '0'+_m),
   _d = e.date.getDate(),
   day = (_d > 9 ? _d : '0'+_d);
});
```

Check  http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/ for details and original source